# ORA-00904 Invalid Identifier - Update Statement With Two Tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working with PeopleSoft Campus Solutions, and we need to update about 22,000 rows of data. This is data between the tables of ACAD_PLAN_VW and ACAD_PROG. Students are listed on both, so their IDs match between the two.

Basically what we are trying to do is say that when the ID, academic career, student career number, effective sequence, and effective date match, AND where the academic plan (their degree, as stored on the ACAD_PLAN_VW) is a specific value, update the ACAD_PROG on the ACAD_PROG table to X value.

I tried to do some very interesting combinations of FROM statements, constantly getting errors. After some researching, I found out that SQLTools doesn't really like FROM statements within UPDATE statements, so I rewrote it to just make the connections manually. I'm assuming I'm doing this right, unless I need to reword it.

The statement I have is:

```
UPDATE PS_ACAD_PROG SET PS_ACAD_PROG.ACAD_PROG = 'UGDS'
WHERE PS_ACAD_PLAN_VW.EMPLID = PS_ACAD_PROG.EMPLID
AND PS_ACAD_PLAN_VW.ACAD_CAREER = PS_ACAD_PROG.ACAD_CAREER
AND PS_ACAD_PLAN_VW.STDNT_CAR_NBR = PS_ACAD_PROG.STDNT_CAR_NBR
AND PS_ACAD_PLAN_VW.EFFSEQ = PS_ACAD_PROG.EFFSEQ
AND PS_ACAD_PLAN_VW.EFFDT = PS_ACAD_PROG.EFFDT
AND PS_ACAD_PLAN_VW.ACAD_PLAN = 'DSTDS'
```

Theoretically, I would assume that this would update any student who has those connections. However, the error that I'm currently getting is as follows:

> ORA-00904: "PS_ACAD_PLAN_VW"."ACAD_PLAN": invalid identifier

I have, as of yet, been unable to figure out the issue. I do have the correct access to view and update those fields, and the field does indeed exist.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle doesn't know it should use the PS_ACAD_PLAN_VW table. Somehow you should reference it.

For example can you try this way?

```
UPDATE (
  select
    PS_ACAD_PROG.ACAD_PROG,
    PS_ACAD_PLAN_VW.ACAD_PLAN
  from
    PS_ACAD_PROG,
    PS_ACAD_PLAN_VW
  where
    PS_ACAD_PLAN_VW.EMPLID = PS_ACAD_PROG.EMPLID
    AND PS_ACAD_PLAN_VW.ACAD_CAREER = PS_ACAD_PROG.ACAD_CAREER
    AND PS_ACAD_PLAN_VW.STDNT_CAR_NBR = PS_ACAD_PROG.STDNT_CAR_NBR
    AND PS_ACAD_PLAN_VW.EFFSEQ = PS_ACAD_PROG.EFFSEQ
    AND PS_ACAD_PLAN_VW.EFFDT = PS_ACAD_PROG.EFFDT
)
SET
  ACAD_PROG = 'UGDS'
WHERE
  ACAD_PLAN = 'DSTDS'
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.I just tried that as well, and it got down to the final line and gave out the same error.

Comment: Can you try to remove the PS_ACAD_PLAN_VW. from the last field reference? or maybe the PS_ACAD_PROG. as well. (test it somewhere before running on production system...)

Comment: I removed the PS_ACAD_PLAN_VW from the final line. It then erred and said that the PS_ACAD_PROG.ACAD_PROG was invalid. Removing PS_ACAD_PROG. from the front of that line grants me a different error:

> ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Comment: I reorganized a bit the query. Can you try it again?

Comment: The error I get then is
ORA-01179: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table

Comment: Ehh. Sorry. Probably you should add the primary keys to between the select/from and maybe rename them if there is a name conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the table which is not getting identified,by keeping in where clause so that you can use the select statement.That will help identifying the tables.

Answer (score 0):

The following implementation should work:

```
UPDATE PS_ACAD_PROG 
   SET ACAD_PROG = 'UGDS'
 WHERE ROWID IN(SELECT PROG.ROWID 
                  FROM PS_ACAD_PROG PROG
                     , PS_ACAD_PLAN_VW PLAN
                 WHERE PLAN.EMPLID        = PROG.EMPLID
                   AND PLAN.ACAD_CAREER   = PROG.ACAD_CAREER
                   AND PLAN.STDNT_CAR_NBR = PROG.STDNT_CAR_NBR
                   AND PLAN.EFFSEQ        = PROG.EFFSEQ
                   AND PLAN.EFFDT         = PROG.EFFDT
                   AND PLAN.ACAD_PLAN     = 'DSTDS');
```